# How to extrapolate values in one AWS CLI output with values from two separate CLI outputs as input files?

Tags: jq, amazon-iam

I am trying to build an audit/compliance report from IAM identity center. We need a list of groups and the respective group members. At current count we have 1,500+ users and 700+ Groups across 120 accounts in AWS.

There isn't an API command to spit this data out, so I'm putting a few commands together to extract the groups to files in Cloudshell. Then I need to cross-reference and throw everything into a CSV for filtering in Excel for the auditors.

- Retrieve UserName and UserID - store in `UserID.json`

  ```
  aws identitystore list-users --identity-store-id d-123456789| jq '.Users[] | {Name: .UserName, ID:.UserId}' > UsersIds.json
  ```
- Retrieve Groups and GroupIDs - store in `GroupsID.json`

  ```
  aws identitystore list-groups --identity-store-id d-123456789| jq '.Groups[] | {GroupName: .DisplayName, ID:.GroupId}' > GroupsID.json
  ```
- Retrieve list of All Users per Group - store in `GroupMembers.json`

  ```
  result=$(aws identitystore list-groups --identity-store-id d-123456789| jq -r '.Groups[].GroupId')

  for val in $result; do
      aws identitystore list-group-memberships --identity-store-id d-123456789--group-id $val | jq -r '.GroupMemberships[] | \
      {GroupID: .GroupId, Member:User.Id} ' >> GroupMembers.json
  done
  ```

Example output from `UserIds.json`:

```json
{
  "Name": "first.last@example.com",
  "ID": "123456789-9876543210-ABCD-4321-1234"
}
{
  "Name": "last.first@example.com",
  "ID": "12345678-4321-1234-2233-9876543210"
}
```

Example output from `GroupsID.json`:

```json
{
  "GroupName": "sso-aws-zone-role-CloudCoreOps",
  "ID": "123456789-55668877-1234-5522-2255-987654321"
}
{
  "GroupName": "sso-aws-zone-role-CloudCoreRO",
  "ID": "1234567890-11224455-2255-5522-1343-9876543210"
}
```

Example Output from `GroupsMembers.json`:

```json
{
  "GroupID": "123456789-55668877-1234-5522-2255-987654321",
  "Member": "123456789-9876543210-ABCD-4321-1234"
}
{
  "GroupID": "1234567890-11224455-2255-5522-1343-9876543210",
  "Member": "12345678-4321-1234-2233-9876543210"
}
```

Now I just need to correlate and I have read you can use JQ like SED. So, that means I should be able to replace the key values in `GroupMembers.json`. First is to replace the GroupID with the correct GroupName matched from the `GroupsID.json` file and the Member with the User Name that matches the ID from the `UserID.json` file.

I think this can be done in a loop, but I want need to learn not only how to do this, but the best way.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be doable with `INDEX` and `JOIN` in a two-level nesting:

```bash
jq --slurpfile users UserIds.json --slurpfile groups GroupsID.json '
  JOIN($groups | INDEX(.ID);
    JOIN($users | INDEX(.ID); .; .Member; add);
  .GroupID; add) | {Name, GroupName}
' GroupsMembers.json
```

```json
{
  "Name": "first.last@example.com",
  "GroupName": "sso-aws-zone-role-CloudCoreOps"
}
{
  "Name": "last.first@example.com",
  "GroupName": "sso-aws-zone-role-CloudCoreRO"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This throws 
jq: error: JOIN/4 is not defined at <top-level>, line 2:
  JOIN($groups | INDEX(.ID);  
jq: 1 compile error

Comment: You are probably using an old version. `INDEX` and `JOIN` were introduced in jq 1.6. Try defining them by yourself as `def INDEX(stream; idx_expr): reduce stream as $row ({}; .[$row|idx_expr|tostring] = $row); def INDEX(idx_expr): INDEX(.[]; idx_expr);` and `def JOIN($idx; stream; idx_expr; join_expr): stream | [., $idx[idx_expr]] | join_expr;` (Taken from the jq [source code](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L283).)

Comment: That's correct. Cloudshell has 1.5 installed and no tools to run make or make install. Have to download the files and run them locally

Comment: Just prepend your filter with the functions yourself. I have copied them into my last comment. They'll work just fine with jq 1.5.

Comment: The answer posted works when using jq 1.6. Downloaded the files from CS and ran them locally.